# The tuleap update make the navbar unresponsive

Tags: navbar, tuleap

When I try to update my VM that host my tuleap forge with yum tools, I lost access to the drop-down menus of the forge web interface.

I can just rollback to the last snapshot to solve this problem. Is a way to keep the forge up to date exist?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow [this guide](http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/update.html?highlight=upgrade#upgrade) to proceed to the update? Try to issue a `service httpd restart` to see if it fixes your problem. If not, delete the file you will find at `/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/scripts/combined/*.js` and 
`service httpd restart` and then reload your page.

If you follow correctly the instructions in the guide you should be able to update smoothly.

Comment: I haven't got any script in this directory so I rollback my VM to the state before update. Then I follow instructions in the guide using "yum update" instead of "yum update [tuleap*]" in order to upgrade the whole OS. Finally the problem is the same and I lost again access to the drop-down menus of the forge web interface.

Comment: Before the update I've got a file name codendi-1404137586.js in this repository but it disappears during the upgrade. If I save it and restore it after the upgrade, the bug disappears. Is there a cleaner way to do this like regenerate this file after the upgrade?